# Embeded YouTube video not available in iframe HTML

Tags: html, video, iframe, youtube

I have a list of embedded youtube videos. My problem is that out of the four videos I display one returns the error: `Video not available`.

I have tried changing the browser, but it doesn't work either. I have also checked if the video allows being embedded on external sides. If I look at the console of my browser no exception is thrown.

```html
    <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 single_item vid">
    <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KdbDDVcw7qc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <figcaption class="overlay">
    </figcaption>
    </li>
```

Has anyone an idea, why this video doesn't work, but all others do?

Comment: It works for me. You may test it when it was new on youtube and was being processed

Comment: Can you see that video in youtube directly? It may be blocked in your country.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I changed the link to a new one - the video you tried worked for me as well. Can you try it again now?

Comment: The new one also works for me. If you have plenty of videos in one page, try a single one. There may be a network error when you have multiple requests in same time.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I deleted the other Videos and it´s still not working. I get the same error from YouTube everytime.

Comment: I get an error playing the embed, but not when viewing directly on yT. The only thing I can think is that because it's "unlisted" that might have an impact?

Comment: it works here as well [link] (https://codepen.io/mohammadyaaser/pen/ZEYaygw)

Comment: It most certainly seems like an issue with your device, rather than YouTube or the code. Have you tested on a different device? Your mobile phone or another computer, for instance?  Alternatively - Maybe it could be a network issue? Is it a particularly large / high res video which you are trying to stream on a unstable network? If so, try changing the video quality settings to Low on the actual video player when it loads

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YouTube forbids embedding some videos in a `localhost environment` without a public domain, but your video can be embedded with no issue through a `public domain/ sub-domain` try the same using webhosting apps or online html tools.

Comment: So you think if he sets up a webhost with a public domain, it should work?

Comment: yes, it will work. I have tried it. Some videos may have some restrictions regarding community policies I think that is the reason why some videos may show as unavailable

Comment: @Lukas you can try tool such as localtunnel to test it on public domain

Comment: Thats exactly what happened to me, thanks for sharing, and thanks to @BrunoWieczorek localtunnel it's amazing.

Answer (score 4):

It works perfectly. I tried embedding four different videos and all of them works well. Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/Arpit09/kt1dwqjp/7/

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KdbDDVcw7qc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I copied the exact same link but it didn‘t worked for me. I really don‘t know what the problem might be. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Thats wierd. Are you able to stream this particular video on youtube.com ?

Comment: @mrbeans Have you tried the link, which he provided in his question?

Comment: @Lukas I can see only embedded link which is mentioned in the question  https://www.youtube.com/embed/KdbDDVcw7qc?rel=0 are you referring to this link or some other link?

Comment: @mrbeans Yeah, I´m able to watch the Video on YouTube. It´s my own Video which I made. I also tried to reupload it and then try it again. But that hadn´t worked either.

Comment: Are you logged in at YouTube? Which Country do you live?

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen What do you mean by logged in? We both live in Austria.

Answer (score 3):

We had a very similar issue yet none of the standard approaches listed here and in other SO questions answered / solved our issue.

In our case, the issue was limited to videos that had License content typically Music Style videos from the well known artists.

The issue did not happen when the video was not licensed. I know some artists can flag that their videos are not shareable, and, domains can be allowed / blocked etc. However, we know that none of these related to us.

Instead the issue was the Referer Policy. I suspect Google / Youtube for licensed content builds a trust model, and part of that trust model expects a strong Referer policy.

We solved our issue by setting the Referer Policy [MDN Refer Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) to a stronger referer policy.

If we used the the default:

> 'no-referrer-when-downgrade'

the video when played would say Video not available.

We changed to:

> origin-when-cross-origin

the video played successfully

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to see the video on the JSFiddle link that MrBean provided, then 
there is something wrong with your **device**, rather than the embed itself.

If that's the case, isolating the problem is the next step.

Have you tried:

1. A different browser. (Perhaps there's a problem with one of your extensions, or your cache.)
2. A different computer on the network. (Perhaps there's a problem with your security settings or firewall filter.)
3. A different computer on a different network. (This will emulate most users, which have reported to be able to see the video correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

This video should work, but you may not have access to view or display it.

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail please?

Comment: @Lukas I've never been interested in `iframe` or embedding YT movies on my own site.
It is possible that you are using a VPN (like me) and your location does not allow you to see the movie.

It's possible that it's the Internet or its provider's fault that is simply blocking some content.

The same thing happens in my browser, I also can't view the video (VPN guilt set to america) if you want to ask me to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this line in the document head, I removed it and it started working

```
<meta name='referrer' content='no-referrer'/>
```